# Expo React Native SVG - animation of 3 lines

Tags: react-native, expo, react-animated

I have a burger menu I made myself and need help to animate it on an onPress={} event,

```
<Svg style={svgStyles}>
<Line
    x1={4}
    y1={6}
    x2={20}
    y2={6}
    stroke="white"
    strokeWidth={2}
    strokeLinecap="round"
/>
<Line
    x1={4}
    y1={12}
    x2={20}
    y2={12}
    stroke="white"
    strokeWidth={2}
    strokeLinecap="round"
/>
<Line
    x1={4}
    y1={18}
    x2={20}
    y2={18}
    stroke="white"
    strokeWidth={2}
    strokeLinecap="round"
/>
```

I want the middle line to shrink to the center, after that simultaneously let the first line drop down to y2={18} and third line to y2={6} to form a cross.
This should happen on an onPress function...
The "setNativeProps" kind of works but not on the onPress function.
How would you guys implement this? 
thanks for your help! 
All the best!

Answer (score 1):

You do this by using the following code. Also, I've provided a link of my git repo with your code as running example. you can also checkout other SVG and Animation examples as well.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Animated, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Svg } from 'expo'; // Supported builtin module
const { Line } = Svg;

class Burger extends React.Component {

    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            _lineOne: new Animated.Value(6),
            _lineTwo_x1: new Animated.Value(4),
            _lineThree: new Animated.Value(18),
        }
    }

    invokeAnimation = () => {        
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(this.state._lineOne, {
            toValue: 18,
            duration: 1500,
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state._lineTwo_x1, {
                toValue: 12,
                duration: 1500,
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state._lineThree, {
                toValue: 6,
                duration: 1500,
            }),
        ]).start();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.state._lineOne.addListener( (progress) => {
            this._lineOne.setNativeProps({ y2: progress.value.toString() });
        });
        this.state._lineThree.addListener( (progress) => {
            this._lineThree.setNativeProps({ y2: progress.value.toString() });
        });
        this.state._lineTwo_x1.addListener( (progress) => {
            this._lineTwo.setNativeProps({ 
                x1: progress.value.toString(),
                x2:  (24 - progress.value).toString(),
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={() => this.invokeAnimation()}>
                <Svg fill="#000" height={24} width={24}>
                    <Line
                        x1={4}
                        y1={6}
                        x2={20}
                        y2={6}
                        stroke="#000000"
                        strokeWidth={2}
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        ref={ ref => this._lineOne = ref }
                    />
                    <Line
                        x1={4}
                        y1={12}
                        x2={20}
                        y2={12}
                        stroke="#000000"
                        strokeWidth={2}
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        ref={ ref => this._lineTwo = ref }
                    />
                    <Line
                        x1={4}
                        y1={18}
                        x2={20}
                        y2={18}
                        stroke="#000000"
                        strokeWidth={2}
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        ref={ ref => this._lineThree = ref }
                    />
                </Svg>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 10
    },
});

export default Burger;
```

https://github.com/pankaj1433/React-Native-SVG-Animation/blob/master/src/components/animationExample/burger.js